# login with Twitter account

Tags: php, twitter

We are developing a website using php, in that user can sign-up or sign-in using twitter account.

when the user click on the twitter button, it should take you to the twitter login page. after your login is successful twitter should able to forward me back to my page webpage.

Please let me know.

Comment: How much you are gonna pay me for the code?

Comment: Rama Moorthy:)i think u have successfully created ur login with facebook account now its time for twitter ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

here be your answer http://dev.twitter.com/pages/sign_in_with_twitter

Answer (score 0):

[Example describes](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/oauth/single-user-with-examples) how to get started using OAuth directly with an access token in Twitter using twitterizer library.