# twitter login in my site

Tags: php

I have done a facebook login in my site.That is users can login in my site using their

facebook account.Similarly I want to do the twitter login in mysite that is users can login

in my site using their twitter account.How it could be done ?. Can any one provide the php

code for this.For this I have created a twitter app.

Comment: possible duplicate of [login with Twitter account](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6097018/login-with-twitter-account)

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a website where you can get developers to write code for you for free. Please try yourself, and if you get stuck with a particular aspect, ask a specific question on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following post should provide you with a good example on how to achieve this -

[Login with Facebook and Twitter](http://www.9lessons.info/2011/02/login-with-facebook-and-twitter.html)

Another post to use - [How to Authenticate Users With Twitter OAuth](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-authenticate-users-with-twitter-oauth/)

Comment: I have done it with the above code but I have an error like this   "Failed to validate oauth signature and token "

Comment: It might be that your time and twitter's time are out of sync - https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth/issues/44

Comment: there is 30 mins time diffrence between server time twitter's time.Is this the issue?

Comment: Quoted from the link I sent in the previous comment  `abraham commented 2 years ago
Check that the time on your server matches the time of Twitter's servers. If they are different by more then 5 minutes Twitter will refuse your connection.`